# How to traverse graph using neo4j core traversal algo in neo4j v2.0

Tags: java, neo4j

I checked the code in the neo4j manual and changed version to 2.0
The code at this [link](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html) looks like this:

```
for ( Path position : Traversal.description()
    .depthFirst()
    .relationships( Rels.KNOWS )
    .relationships( Rels.LIKES, Direction.INCOMING )
    .evaluator( Evaluators.toDepth( 5 ) )
    .traverse( node ) ){
output += position + "\n";}
```

When I write the same code in my program, it gives me deprecation warning for `org.neo4j.kernel.Traversal`.

My question is for neo4j v2.0 what is the way to do traversals using core java API. I also tried the same using cypher queries but they are slow (takes more than 1 sec) for my queries and I have read in the comparison [here](http://www.rene-pickhardt.de/get-the-full-neo4j-power-by-using-the-core-java-api-for-traversing-your-graph-data-base-instead-of-cypher-query-language/) that java traversal APIs are faster than cypher ones.

I also want to try out dijkstra algorithm in neo4j but when I try the code given in the manual for dijkstra I again get the deprecation warning.

Where can I find the examples/code illustrating the use of core java traversal API in neo4j v2.0 ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the new [TraversalDescription](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/traversal/TraversalDescription.html)-framework. The TraversalDescription-object is accessable via your GraphDatabaseService by calling traversalDescription() on it. Defining the traversal then is similar to the old methods.